# Can't use variable in defining array value?

Tags: java, variables, multidimensional-array

So I have a problem where Java is telling me that the following line is an illegal start of expression and not a statement and ';' expected, etc...

The expression is:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[][] coords = new int[24][2];
start = rand.nextInt(16);
coords[0][0]={0,start};
```

What's wrong with that expression?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to assign in the last line there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `coords[0][0]={0,start};`, `{0, start}` is simply not a valid expression. It *looks* like you're trying to initialize the first row of the array, in which case you're looking for something along these lines:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[][] coords = new int[24][2];
start = rand.nextInt(16);
coords[0][0] = 0;
coords[0][1] = start;
```

Comment: Wow...I forgot one of the most important rules of defining arrays...I should probably study them a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[][] coords = new int[24][2];
coords[0] = new int[] {0, rand.nextInt(16)};
```

is also valid.  This is more in the spirit of what you were attempting, but there isn't much difference between this and the above answer.